# regexp_extract to find the value in Hive

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, hive

I'm new to `regexp_extract` and need to split the column on `/` and then pick the 3rd value.  For example, from

```
application/motorola products/routers
```

would want to get  `routers`.  If there is no 3rd value, then we need to fall back on the 2nd value, which would be `motorola products`.  I tried the following regex pattern but it doesn't work:

```
(.*?\/)(.*?\/)(.*?)(\/.*\/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saying a single character is optional. Give the `.` a [quantifier](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) `*` or `+`. I think this regex would actually be better:

```
(?:([^\/]+?\/)([^\/]+?)\/([^\/]*)|([^\/]+?\/)([^\/]+))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dX6uQ9/2

I haven't worked with/don't have `hive` so can't confirm this will work but I think it should put you in a closer direction.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want the *last* value, meaning whatever is after the last `/`.  The regex for that would be `[^/]+$`:

```
select regexp_extract(name, '[^/]+$', 0) from dummy;
```

If there are two slashes, you get the third value.  If there are five slashes, you get the sixth value.

If you want to stop at the third value even if there are more than two slashes, you can use this:

```
select regexp_extract(name, '^(?:[^/]+/){0,2}([^/]+)', 1) from dummy;
```

The index argument, `1`, makes it extract what was matched in the first capturing group, `([^/]+)`.

Note: I'm assuming the complete value won't *start* or *end* with a slash, like `/motorola products/routers` or `application/motorola products/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select split('application/motorola products/routers','/')[size(split('application/motorola products/routers','/'))-1]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value